# How to backup my Node.js setup when upgrading

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I want to upgrade Node.js on Ubuntu, but I want to make sure that if anything goes wrong I could revert back my source code, installed modules and `node` binary to the working setup. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install any version of node.js just go to [downloads](http://nodejs.org/download/). Go into [Other Releases](http://nodejs.org/dist/) and download what version you want with respect to your OS and 32-bit or 64-bit.
Example:

- `node-vX.XX.X-OS-x64.tar.gz (64-bit)`
- `node-vX.XX.X-OS-x86.tar.gz (32-bit)`

Then, follow the instruction on the github.com. [Building and installing Node.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation#building-and-installing-nodejs)

Another way is to use [`NVM`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), the Node Version Manager (it works in a very similar way to `rvm` for ruby). This allows to install and manage multiple versions of node. Here's a snippet ([source](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#usage)):

```
Usage:
nvm install <version>       Download and install a <version>
nvm use <version>           Modify PATH to use <version>
nvm ls                      List versions (installed versions are blue)
```

You can also check this [**`n`**](https://github.com/visionmedia/n). A Simple flavour of node binary management.

---

**Update** (as per comments):
If you have installed the nvm after node.js. You can check already installed by using `nvm ls` which lists already installed version(s) ready to use.

> amolkulkarni@ubuntu:~$ nvm ls 
>   current: v0.10.18

Comment: I didn't see anything in the docs about this, but perhaps you can elaborate (thanks btw, i didn't know about NVM).  If you already have an existing node package say for v 0.8.17.  You then install NVM; would it be necessary to nvm install that same version again, or does NVM automagically detect this?

Comment: @thtsigma You can check it by using `nvm ls` command which lists all the installed version(s) available for use. So already installed version will appear in that. Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should use Node Version Manager https://github.com/creationix/nvm